# Display message after logging out with JSF and Spring security

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, spring-security, logout

I have an application with Login and Logout actions. After pressing Logout button, I would like to redirect to Login page and display here faces message with an information about a successful logging out. Now, I'm struggling with forwarding of faces message. This message doesn't want to display in Login dialog. Could you please give me any hint or recommend me another way? I'm using JSF 2.1 with Spring Security 4. What I have tried:

**Logout method**

```
public String doLogout() throws ServletException, IOException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = ((HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest());       
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_logout");
    dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest(), (ServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse());

    facesContext.addMessage("", new FacesMessage("You have been successfully logged out."));
    externalContext.getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    return null;
}
```

**Login XHTML**

```
<h:form id="loginForm" prependId="false">
    <p:dialog visible="true" resizable="false" closable="false" draggable="false" position="center">
            <p:messages globalOnly="true" id="msgs"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="User" />
            <p:inputText id="j_username" required="true"/>
            <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password" />
            <p:password id="j_password" required="true"/>
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-check"
                             id="login"  
                             action="#{loginController.doLogin}"
                             oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)"
                             update="msgs"
                             ajax="false"/>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

**Spring security**

```
<http auto-config="true" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/**" 
                   access="ROLE_RA"/>
    <form-login login-page="/pages/userLogin.xhtml"
                default-target-url="/pages/specimens/specimenOverview.xhtml" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/pages/userLogin.xhtml"/>
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/pages/userLogin.xhtml">
      <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"/>
    </session-management>
</http>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just and parameter to logout url:

```
<logout logout-success-url="/pages/userLogin.xhtml?logout=true"/>
```

check it on login page and display your message:

```
<h:outputText value="Your logout message here" rendered="#{param['logout']}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! And is somehow possible to update messages tag after redirecting and recreating session? I would like to use <p:messages> because of styling and overall consistency.

Comment: Technically its possible but will be to complicated. The idea is to process input request parameter inside managed bean and set JSF message here.

Comment: Yes, it was also my idea. But I have a problem to transfer the message if I am redirecting to another page and creating new session. I have tried `externalContext.getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);` but without success.

Comment: No,it's not the same, getFlash() still operate with current session, which will be terminated after logout. You need to send message with newly created session _after_ logout completed.

Comment: @AlexChernyshev This solution sort of works. In my case, it does logout user and display a success message, however, user cannot use the same page to log back in. It gives a http 408 error.